# Multiple datasources type (properties / JNDI) configuration

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project, which can run in standalone mode (.jar and tomcat embedded) or on wildfly server (.war). When running in a standalone mode, database configuration should be in properties file. When running in wildfly, it fetches the configuration from JNDI.

Thing is, when I override the bean definition of the factory bean (as I do not know yet if running in standalone/wildfly mode), how can I fallback to the original factory bean, so that spring boot could correctly load the db config from properties file?

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("server.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"server.domain"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import(value = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class GeneralDatabaseConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.jpa.database")
    private String database;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        if (database == null) {
            //No database in properties file (wildfly mode)
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            emfBean.setDataSource(DataSourceLoader.getDataSource());
            emfBean.setPersistenceUnitName("testserver");
            emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
            emfBean.setSharedCacheMode(SharedCacheMode.ENABLE_SELECTIVE); // Caches only entities with @Cacheable-Annotation
            emfBean.setValidationMode(ValidationMode.NONE);
            return emfBean;
        } else {
            //Standalone mode - get DB config from file as usual
            return **???**
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are making things way to complex. Let Spring Boot handle that for you it is capable of doing either JPA or plain setup. For standalone specify the datasource in an `application.properties` next to the jar. For embedded specify the `spring.datasource.jndi-name` instead of the other `spring.datasource` properties. No need to override anything.

Comment: Thing is, this project should be delivered with the same settings for lots of customers. Therefore we have in properties file just the "mandant" number. And in DB we have mandantNumber -> JNDI name (I have rewritten this logic to just "DataSourceLoader.getDataSource()"). That's why I cannot simply hard-code the JNDI name in properties file. In properties file I have just the mandant number (90% of customers have  the value 1 though).

Comment: `spring.datasource.jndi-name=${spring.jpa.database}` in `application-wildfly.properties` or something and enable that profile when you run on wildfly

Comment: You don't need a database for the properties you can just create a separate `application.properties` and configure it for the client instead the need of a database. Also instead of creating a custom way of loading properties I would suggest a `PropertySource` which loads them from the database, this `PropertySource` you could register with an `ApplicationContextInitializer` and it would work with the normal property support. This is a lot easier then trying to work around things.